# How to make sure that a column containing a certain value will always be on top of all other rows under the same group using SQL?

Tags: sql

I got this table named **applicants**.

```
 id |   app_no   |    name    | birthdate  | country     | score
 1  |    SG03    | John       | 1991-09-01 | Singapore   | 75
 2  |    PH08    | Rachel     | 1990-03-23 | Philippines | 80
 3  |    VN23    | Angel      | 1991-08-09 | Vietnam     | 70
 4  |  PH02-XXX  | Christiane | 1993-05-21 | Philippines | 60
 5  |    MY03    | Cathy      | 1994-02-14 | Malaysia    | 90
 6  |    SG73    | Karen      | 1995-12-02 | Singapore   | 74
 7  |    PH88    | Carlo      | 1991-11-18 | Philippines | 88
 8  |    VN22    | Lorraine   | 1992-01-13 | Vietnam     | 67
 9  |    PH10    | Jessica    | 1996-10-17 | Philippines | 64
10  |  MY29-XXX  | Vanessa    | 1998-12-15 | Malaysia    | 67
11  |    SG90    | Paula      | 1987-04-11 | Singapore   | 89
12  |    PH27    | Eddie      | 1975-06-21 | Philippines | 89
13  |    VN35    | Queenie    | 1986-02-26 | Vietnam     | 78
14  |    JP26    | Alyssa     | 1935-08-25 | Japan       | 97
15  |  SG50-XXX  | Susan      | 1987-09-08 | Singapore   | 94
16  |    MY25    | Jordan     | 1932-11-06 | Malaysia    | 73
17  |    MY73    | Michael    | 1955-02-23 | Malaysia    | 82
18  |    VN92    | Angelo     | 1977-01-12 | Vietnam     | 76
19  |    PH29    | Christine  | 1997-08-22 | Philippines | 61
20  |    VN33    | Andrea     | 1993-07-23 | Vietnam     | 86
```

I want to sort the table items using the following order:

1. country asc
2. score desc
3. birthdate asc

I know that I can do it using `SELECT * FROM applicants ORDER BY country asc, score desc, birthdate asc`.
But, I also want to put the row with an app_no value containing the string "XXX" first before all other rows that have the same country (ignoring the above orders). How should I do this?

The output should be like this:

```
 id |   app_no   |    name    | birthdate  | country     | score
14  |    JP26    | Alyssa     | 1935-08-25 | Japan       | 97
10  |  MY29-XXX  | Vanessa    | 1998-12-15 | Malaysia    | 67
 5  |    MY03    | Cathy      | 1994-02-14 | Malaysia    | 90
17  |    MY73    | Michael    | 1955-02-23 | Malaysia    | 82
16  |    MY25    | Jordan     | 1932-11-06 | Malaysia    | 73
 4  |  PH02-XXX  | Christiane | 1993-05-21 | Philippines | 60
12  |    PH27    | Eddie      | 1975-06-21 | Philippines | 89
 7  |    PH88    | Carlo      | 1991-11-18 | Philippines | 88
 2  |    PH08    | Rachel     | 1990-03-23 | Philippines | 80
 9  |    PH10    | Jessica    | 1996-10-17 | Philippines | 64
19  |    PH29    | Christine  | 1997-08-22 | Philippines | 61
15  |  SG50-XXX  | Susan      | 1987-09-08 | Singapore   | 94
11  |    SG90    | Paula      | 1987-04-11 | Singapore   | 89
 1  |    SG03    | John       | 1991-09-01 | Singapore   | 75
 6  |    SG73    | Karen      | 1995-12-02 | Singapore   | 74
20  |    VN33    | Andrea     | 1993-07-23 | Vietnam     | 86
13  |    VN35    | Queenie    | 1986-02-26 | Vietnam     | 78
18  |    VN92    | Angelo     | 1977-01-12 | Vietnam     | 76
 3  |    VN23    | Angel      | 1991-08-09 | Vietnam     | 70
 8  |    VN22    | Lorraine   | 1992-01-13 | Vietnam     | 67
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column with an `CASE` statement (the syntax may vary based on your RDBMS type), which I am resolving to 1 in case the value in the `app_no` column is XXX, otherwise 0.  Then I would sort the result set in the descending order of that new derived column.

In Oracle:

```
SELECT id, app_no, name, 
CASE WHEN app_no = 'XXX' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isXXX 
FROM applicants ORDER BY isXXX desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your particular flavor of SQL is Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL), then the following should work.

```
ORDER BY country asc, 
         Case When app_no Like '%XXX%' then 0 Else 1 End,             
         score desc, 
         birthdate asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `case` statement in the `order by`, after `country`:

```
ORDER BY country asc, 
         (case when app_no Like '%XXX%' then 0 Else 1 End),
         score desc, birthdate asc
```

Your sample data only has "XXX" at the end, so using `like '%XXX'` is more specific.